# Understanding the tricky 'the'

Tags: grammar, articles

Please determine which sentence is correct and explain why:-

To give your body **the** chance to recover, it is also best to alternate exercise days with rest days.

Or

To give your body **a** chance to recover, it is also **the** best to alternate exercise days with rest days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *chance* is usually one of several possible outcomes. Your body might recover but it is also possible it won't.

For example,

> You have **a chance** to win the lottery, but you have (unfortunately) **a much larger chance** of not winning.

The *chance* not being a specific one, use *a*.

To use *the* you have to refer to a specific chance. For example:

> **The only chance** you have of (doing something) is ...

And you can also use *chances* to refer to those multiple possibilites:

> **Chances are** that you won't win the lottery.

Answer (score 0):

“A chance” is more appropriate. I’d only use a definite article when saying something like “the main chance” or “the only chance,” neither of which is intended or appropriate in your specific example.

Comment: @Costa And omit **the** in front of best. The expression is: **It's best to do.....** as opposed to using **the best** ahead of a noun as in **this is the best option/solution** or whatever..